# D3 - Map with custom json

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, polygon

I would like to draw a custom map using a json that I will get from a webservice thus not in a file.

The json would probably look like this

```
{
    "areas" : [
        {
            "name" : "A",
            "borders" : [[4,50], [4.5,51],...],
            "otherProperty" : "red"
        },
        {
            "name" : "B",
            "borders" : [[3,48] , [3.5,49],...],
            "otherProperty" : "yellow"
        }
    ]
}
```

The borders will draw a polygon that are the borders of the area.

Is it possible to use a Json like this to draw the map ? I can change the json if needed

How can I use this json instead of a file ?

```
 d3.json("myFile.json", function(error, data) {...}
```

**EDIT**

I can use directly

```
g.selectAll('path')
.data(data.areas)
```

but nothing is displayed and no errors

**EDIT 2**

I am using ConicConformal coordinates for the points

> [181096,163474],[180722,164173],[180280,164925],

**EDIT 3**

Here is a not-working [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/44nn26sL/1/)

Comment: can you please provide a link to a jsfiddle?

Comment: It is complicate to create a jsfiddle.. Do you need more information ? What part of the code do you need ?

Comment: Well I've created a jsfiddle which turns your data structure into polygons with the given borders. Hope it answers your question.

Comment: What do the numbers [181096,163474],[180722,164173],[180280,164925] represent? They are not latitude/longitude pairs, are they?

Comment: They are latitude/longiture pairs with the Lambert projection --> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_conformal_conic_projection || That is why I am using the `geoConicConformal`

Comment: So you've done the projection manually. Why do you want to apply it a second time in the code then?

Comment: When using geoConicConformal I should use Mercator latitude/longitude ? I dont really understand what you mean. My coordinates come from a database and I receive them like this

Comment: The latitude/longitude coordinates are not projection dependent. For example, no matter what projection you are using, the coordinates of Greenwhich are N 51.48, E 0.00.

Comment: The projection itself takes care that the same coordinate is rendered at a different position.

Comment: Ooooh...ok.. but then how can I use my coordinates ? eg :[181096,163474]

Comment: That means you already know where to render the points, no need to apply the projection. I cannot try it now, but my code probably works. A slight modification of rescaling might be needed. I'd try dividing the x and y values by let's say 500 in the accessor function.

Comment: It works... Thank you so much ! One last think - The polygons are a little bit to small. How can I "zoom" ? Should I use `scale` ? Where ? In the linefunction ?

Comment: you could use something like `.x(function(d) { return (d[0]-c_1)*c_2; })` for some `c_1` and `c_2` values based on your data, and something similar for `.y`

Comment: Ok I am trying with some random values but hard to find one. Should it be more 10-20 or 10000-20000 ?

Comment: Depends on your data. Think about which range the coordinates you have are in, and what is the size of the svg in which you want to draw the polygons. You could introduce a [linear scale](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale#linear-scales) with the corresponding domain and range.

Comment: Okay perfect ! Thank you so much @elias ! You really really helped me !!

Comment: @elias - Oops I just saw that my polygons are upside-down do you have any idea why ?

Comment: That is a sign of a negative coefficient in the function for y. Try multiplying it by -1 - or if you are using linear scales, swap the endpoints of either the domain, or the range. Something like `.domain([data_min, data_max]).range([0, width])` should do the work.

Comment: Seems logical but now everything is moved and I cannot see the areas anymore and I am not using linear scales. I used your function without interpolate or curve

Comment: I recommend using linear scales. It makes your work much easier. A simple multiplication by -1 won't totally solve your issue, you have to recalculate the translation - which is done automatically by the linear scale if you're using that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123154/discussion-between-weedoze-and-elias).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I got the point of your question.

It should not matter if the json comes from a file or from a webserver, you can give the path or uri in the d3.json call. Or as you posted in your edit, you can use the variable directly.

The structure you gave can be used without any problems.

I assumed you are using D3 v3. [Here](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/SVG-Shapes.md#_line) you can find the corresponding part of the API documentation. Using [this tutorial](https://www.dashingd3js.com/svg-paths-and-d3js) about svg paths I've created [a jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7wmhydsj/1/) which displays polygons with the given json-structure (I've changed the numbers to have a more obvious result).

The following function is responsible to get the proper parts of the data you gave when generating the paths which will be used as your polygons' borders.

```
var lineFunction = d3.svg.line()
                     .x(function(d) { return d[0]; })
                     .y(function(d) { return d[1]; })
                     .interpolate("linear");
```

And this is how you pass it to the line generator:

```
.attr("d",function(d) {return lineFunction(d.borders);})
```

See the fiddle linked above for the complete code.

Comment: This seems to work well in your JsFiddle but my borders are real coordinates. How can I use this with a projection ? It uses geoConicConformal projection

Comment: And I will switch to V4

Comment: @Weedoze, please provide a jsfiddle, so there is less misunderstanding, and to show your efforts.

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/API.md#lines) is the corresponding documentation for D3 v4 by the way.

Comment: JSFiddle added in the question

Comment: Adding a projection changes the question quite radically, I think. [This tutorial](https://bost.ocks.org/mike/map/) was a big help for me. I'm not aware of anything like it using D3 v4 though.

Comment: I already saw this tutorial many times but it is using a GeoJson file. How can I change it using my json that is not formatted a geojson or topojson ?

Comment: I cannot find `interpolate` in D3 V4. I tried witout it and it works ? Is it the good way ?

Comment: it is replaced by `curve`